# Paint a border around every image in a Word document

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

Is there a way to add a border around every image in Word? I know that I can create a custom paragraph style with a border and put the image in there, but maybe I can just specify a global image style, like in CSS:

```
img { border: 1px solid #000 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no picture style concept available in Word. Therefore, something like specifying a global style for images similar to CSS is not possible.

What you can do is write a VBA macro that adds the border to all images. The code is a little different depending on whether your image is formatted to be inline with text (`InlineShape`)  or floating (`Shape`):

```
Sub AddBorderToPictures()

    ' Add border to pictures that are "inline with text"
    Dim oInlineShape As inlineShape
    For Each oInlineShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        oInlineShape.Borders.Enable = True
        oInlineShape.Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorBlack
        oInlineShape.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth100pt
        oInlineShape.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    Next

    ' Add border to pictures that are floating
    Dim oShape As shape
    For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        oShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        oShape.Line.Weight = 1
        oShape.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
    Next

End Sub
```

If apparently setting the line width to `wdLineWidth100pt` is an issue, you can try using the actual underlying integer value instead, e.g.:

```
oInlineShape.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = 8
```

This is how the constant is defined:

```
public enum WdLineWidth
{
    wdLineWidth025pt = 2,
    wdLineWidth050pt = 4,
    wdLineWidth075pt = 6,
    wdLineWidth100pt = 8,
    wdLineWidth150pt = 12,
    wdLineWidth225pt = 18,
    wdLineWidth300pt = 24,
    wdLineWidth450pt = 36,
    wdLineWidth600pt = 48,
}
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, thank you. Can I add this code to a docx file so it is executed automatically every time the file is opened in Word? (I'm sorry I didn't use VBA macros for many years.)

Comment: I tried adding this to my document in Word 365 Mac, but when trying to run it, I get [runtime error 8043](http://pasteboard.co/3hRLwGesT.png).

Comment: If you step through your code, in that line does the error occur?

Comment: Here: `oInlineShape.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth100pt`. I replaced `100pt` with `10pt`, and then it run - but it didn't change any image in the file.